# Node JS Problem: Setting HTTPS Request JSON Object To a Variable

Tags: node.js

I'm not familiar with using node.js and I need help. In https request, I set price_val as a JSON object that has a key "price", and when I did console.log, it printed out the value perfectly fine. However, when I'm trying to get price_val.price from newItem, it just gets an empty string. How do I fix this??

```
price_val = ""

const price_req = https.request(options, (res) => {
let data = ""
res.on('data', (d) => {
    data += d;
});
res.on('end', () => {
    price_val = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(price_val.price)
    });
});

price_req.on('error', (error) => {
console.error(error)
})

price_req.end()

const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
    amount: req.body.amount,
    price: price_val.price
});

newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));
```

});

Comment: Can you please console `JSON.parse(data)` and share.

Comment: Move your `newItem` code INSIDE the `res.on('end', () => {...})` callback.  That's the only place that `price_val` is known to be a good value.  Otherwise, you're trying to use the value BEFORE it has been set.  These callbacks are non-blocking and asynchronous.  They run some time in the future, but your `newItem` code runs before the callbacks have run.  The only place where you know the timing of when the `end` event callback runs is INSIDE the callback or in a function that you call from there.